# "React is not defined" when importing React components from other package with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am importing a JSX component from [`@platformatic/ui-components`](https://github.com/platformatic/ui-components), but I have the following problem when using a simple code like

```
import { BorderedBox } from '@platformatic/ui-components'
function App() {
  return <BorderedBox>Hello World!</BorderedBox>
}
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at BorderedBox (BorderedBox.jsx:10:3)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
```

It seems that adding `import React from 'react'` in each component I export would fix the problem but it doesn't sound right to me.

I maintain also `@platformatic/ui-components` so I can change the library accordingly.

Repo for minimal reproduction: https://github.com/leorossi/plt-ui

Comment: Why doesn't it sound right to import `React` in each component? Each component uses `React`. The [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) `<BorderedBox>Hello World!</BorderedBox>` is transposed into `React.createElement(BorderedBox, {}, "Hello World!")`

Comment: Because I am mostly a backend developer 

Comment: Anyway I thought that importing React on the root component (which renders `<App />` would be enough for the transpiler.